# React Use State Containing JSON Object Reverts Updates?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Running into a really weird issue. I have a Postgres table which upon program startup, loads a bunch of values into a JSON object stored as a Use State Object at the start. It is a big object, but I will give you an example below.

```
const [person, setPerson] = useState({
id: 0,
name: "John Smith"
phones: [{
   number: "(111) 111-1111"
   type: "Cell"
   }]
})
```

When I use setPerson to update the JSON object, I am doing it as such:

```
setPerson({
...person,
name: "New Name"
})
```

The update takes place, and I see the dashboard dynamically change. However, when I run my next update, for example:

```
let new_phones = person.phones.push({
   number: "new number",
   type: "Cell"
})

setPerson({
...person,
phones: new_phones
})
```

What ends up happening is that the phones correctly update, and I now see my two phones shown instead of one. However, the updated name reverts to the old name. Instead of showing "New Name" as it should, it goes back to showing the name before any updates took place, "John Smith".

The only fields that don't get reverted would be the fields in Person that contain an array. If I make another change after updating phones, phones will not revert back to only containing 1 object. It will still show 2. The fields that revert at the static fields that contain strings, ints, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update a `state` depending on a previous `state`, your code will not ensure getting the latest snapshot unless you use **updater function**.

```
// ❌ bad and not accurate way to update state depending on previous one

setPerson({
  ...person,
  name: "New Name"
})

setPerson({
  ...person,
  phones: new_phones
})

// ✅ use updater function instead

setPerson(prevState => 
return {
  ...prevState,
  name: "New Name"
})

setPerson(prevState => 
return {
  ...prevState,
  phones: {
   number: "new number",
   type: "Cell"
  }
})
```

Also, **be aware** of codes like `person.phones.push` because this one will mutate your state and this is not the correct way of updating react states. (this one is most likely responsible for the issues in your case)

[Read more about updating state depending on previous state](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state)

[What's a mutation?](https://react.dev/learn/updating-objects-in-state#whats-a-mutation)

Comment: This is helpful... how would I go about removing a item from the phones array? Or updating one of the items based on a unique id value stored within the object?

Comment: if `person` could contain multiple _Persons_, first you would convert `person` to `array` instead of `object`. Now you have array of objects and you can easily update or delete any of them depending on the `id` with the help of [.filter() method.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: I meant how would I update a sole Person's object that contains the Phone array of phone objects. In your example above you showed how to add to the Phone object, but I would like to know the correct way to delete and update the phone objects so that the Person object takes the update and I'm not experiencing the same error I was.